# pygameでの画像読み込みがうまくいきません

Tags: python, pygame

pygameを使用してゲーム制作を始めてみたいと思い、以下のURLを参考にまずはpng画像を
用いたマップの作成からやってみようと思ったのですが、画像のロードがうまく行きません。

参考URL : http://aidiary.hatenablog.com/entry/20080524/1275748651

以下にソースコードとエラーメッセージを記述します。

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import sys
import os

SCR_RECT = Rect(0,0,640,480)
ROW,COL = 15,20 # mapsize 10*20マス
GS = 32 # pixelsize
# mapdata
map = [[0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
       [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
       [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
       [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
       [2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1],
       [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
       [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
       [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
       [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
       [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
       [2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1],
       [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2],
       [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1],
       [1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0],
       [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1]]

def load_image(filename, colorkey=None):
        filename = os.path.join("C:\python_images\フォルダ名", filename)
        try:
                image = pygame.image.load(filename)
        except pygame.error as message:
                print ("Cannot load image:" + filename)
                raise SystemExit(message)
        image = image.convert()
        if colorkey is not None:
                if colorkey is -1:
                        colorkey = image.get_at((0,0))
                image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)
        return image

def draw_map(screen):
        # map の描画
        for r in range (ROW):
                for c in range(COL):
                        if map[r][c] == 0:
                                screen.blit(tileImg0,(c*GS,r*GS))
                        elif map[r][c] == 1:
                                screen.blit(tileImg1,(c*GS,r*GS))
                        elif map[r][c] == 2:
                                screen.blit(tileImg2,(c*GS,r*GS))

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCR_RECT.size)
pygame.display.set_caption("map")

#imageload
tileImg0 = load_image('ファイル名01.png')
tileImg1 = load_image('ファイル名02.png')
tileImg2 = load_image('ファイル名03.png')

while True:
        draw_map(screen)
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                        sys.exit()
                if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        sys.exit()
```

エラーメッセージ :

```
Cannot load image:C:\python_images\フォルダ名\ファイル名01.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OWNER\Desktop\プログラム名.py", line 29, in load_image
    image = pygame.image.load(filename)
pygame.error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OWNER\Desktop\プログラム名.py", line 56, in <module>
    tileImg0 = load_image('ファイル名01.png')
  File "C:\Users\OWNER\Desktop\プログラム名.py", line 32, in load_image
    raise SystemExit(message)
SystemExit
```

肝心の質問ですが、どうすれば画像をうまく読み込んでマップ描画ができるか解決方法が
分からないので教えていただきたいです。
Pythonでのプログラミング自体も始めて日が浅く、エラーの細かい部分等も理解できない
ような若輩者ですが、回答のほどよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

これは、ディレクトリの指定の方法が間違えていますね。
`import os`,で、`os.getcwd()`を調べ、現在どのディレクトリの情報を取得しようとしているのかをチェックしてください。これは、現在のディレクトリ（カレントディレクトリ）を調べられる関数です。今たちまちそのPythonファイルがあるディレクトリが返ってくると思います。こう書くと、より汎用的な動作になると思います。少し、あなたのディレクトリ関係がわからないので、仮定を交えてかきたいとおもいます。
　あなたの現在実行中のコードがあるディレクトリを、現在のディレクトリとします。
　あなたは、その中にある、さらに設けられたフォルダ内の、イメージを取り出したいとします。
　これをサブディレクトリとし、そのフォルダこそが、python_imagesフォルダであると、私は
　思い込んでいます。
　`import os`
  (省略)
  `filename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "\\python_images\\"+filename)`
  　こうしておけば、どのような場合でも、そのコードを実行したいディレクトリの中の、
　python_imagesフォルダの中にある、あなたが取り出したい画像ファイルが、ゲット
　できるんじゃないかなと思います。予防線を張っておきますが、pygameは、1年以上
　前でいったん中断しています。確かこれでよかったと思いますが、とりあえず試して
　みてくださいませ。あと、老婆心ながら、フォルダの指定の時には、Uなど、文字によっては
　スラッシュの後に、特定のアルファベットが来ると、別の文字だと解釈されることがあ
　りますから、\2本引いたほうがいいと思いますよ。`"python_images\\"+filename`
  にするべきだったか少し自信がありません。
　あと、私の経験から、pythonインタプリタ（初期から付属してあるIDE)で、`os.getcwd()`
  を使うと、違う場所が返ってくることがあります。。しっかりと、エディタに書いてから実行し　たほうが、　正確な情報が返ってくると思います。2+3=5って返してくれるから便利なんですけ　ど、たまにドジをします。もしうまくいかなければ、またコメントをください。参考になれば幸　いです。

Comment: ご教示ありがとうございます。情報をうまく書き込めていませんでしたが、コード自体をデスクトップに保存し、読み込みたい画像の入ったフォルダをCドライブ直下に作成したpython_imagesというフォルダに保存してしまっておりました。なので、回答を参考にコードと同じくデスクトップに画像の入ったフォルダを移してきて、`filename = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "\\Disbelief_maps\\"+filename)`に差し替えて実行してみましたところ、エラーが出てきてしまいました。パスがうまく取得できているか確認してみようと、上記のコードの直前に`print(os.getcwd())`、直後に`print(filename)`を付加して実行してみたところ、`C:\Users\OWNER\Desktop
\Disbelief_maps\tile01.png
Cannot load image:\Disbelief_maps\tile01.png
`と表示され、画像読み込みのエラーが発生していたので、うまくパスの結合ができてないのかな？と思ったのですが、よく分からなかったためよろしければそこも教えていただけると幸いです。

Comment: 何度もすみません。どうやら`file‌​name = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "\\Disbelief_maps\\"+filename)`の`"\\Disbelief_maps\\"`部分の最初の \\ が必要なかったみたいで、os.path.join側で自動的に修正してくれるという仕様だといろいろ検索していたところ判明し、うまくマップの描画が出来ました。とても助かりました。ありがとうございます。